# Pasar valor de un select a select modal

Tags: javascript, sql, select, modal

Buenas estoy haciendo una edición de formulario a través de modal. He conseguido pasar todos los datos necesarios a través de javascript, pero no se como pasar el valor de un select a el select del modal.

El select es el estado de Activado, Desactivado, y en la Bd el Activado es el valor 1 y desactivado el valor 0.

Paso a exponer como mando y recibo los datos en el modal:

Esto es uno de los tantos datos que mando, pero pongo solo uno para no llenar el post mucho.

```
<td class="tdfgaz" id="Name<?php echo $res['IdUsuario']; ?>"><?php echo $res['Nombre']; ?></td>
```

Con este SCRIPT mando los datos al modal:

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $(document).on('click', '.edit', function(){
                var id=$(this).val();
                var IdUsuario=$('#IdUsuario'+id).text();
                var Name=$('#Name'+id).text();
                var Nif=$('#Nif'+id).text();
                var Direccion=$('#Direccion'+id).text();
                var Poblacion=$('#Poblacion'+id).text();
                var Postal=$('#Postal'+id).text();
                var Provincia=$('#Provincia'+id).text();
                var Email=$('#Email'+id).text();
                var Telefono=$('#Telefono'+id).text();
                var Movil=$('#Movil'+id).text();
                var Web=$('#Web'+id).text();
                var Informacion=$('#Informacion'+id).text();

                $('#edit').modal('show');
                $('#eIdUsuario').val(IdUsuario);
                $('#eName').val(Name);
                $('#eNif').val(Nif);
                $('#eDireccion').val(Direccion);
                $('#ePoblacion').val(Poblacion);
                $('#ePostal').val(Postal);
                $('#eProvincia').val(Provincia);
                $('#eEmail').val(Email);
                $('#eTelefono').val(Telefono);
                $('#eMovil').val(Movil);
                $('#eWeb').val(Web);
                $('#eInformacion').val(Informacion);

            });
        });
    </script>
```

Y de este modo los imprimo en los input del modal:

```
  <div class="form-group">
   <label>Nombre</label>
   <input type="text" class="form-control inputmiocont corpiii" id="eName" name="eName">
   </div>
```

El campo del select lo tengo así:

```
<td class="otrotdfgaz">
 <?php
   if ($res['intestado'] == 1) echo "<span class=\"conect-label\">Activado</span>"; else
   echo "<span class=\"desconect-label\">Desactivado</span>";
 ?>
</td>
```

**Corrijo para poner las ediciones:**

Aqui se imprime primero el valor de la BD, en una tabla:

```
<td class="otrotdfgaz" id="select2-1<?php echo $res['IdUsuario']; ?>">
  <?php
   if ($res['intestado'] == 1) echo "<span class=\"conect-label\">Activado</span>";
   else echo "<span class=\"desconect-label\">Desactivado</span>";
  ?>
</td>
```

El código JavaScript que lo envía al modal:

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $(document).on('click', '.edit', function(){
                var id=$(this).val();
                var Estado=$('#select2-1'+id).children('span').first().text();


                $('#select2-1').val(Estado);


            });
        });
 </script>
```

Aquí es donde tiene que imprimir con un selected el valor que viene del td.
Además que también este la otra opción para poder cambiarla.

```
<select id="select2-1" value="" class="form-control" name="estado">
  <option value="1">Activado</option>
  <option value="0">Desactivado</option>
</select>
```

Comment: tienes un select en un td ? que error te da ? ese codigo ?

Comment: No me da ningún error, solo quiero pasar el valor del select como estoy haciendo con el resto de datos. Ese Php es por que los valores del estado en la BD están como 1 activado 0 desactivado, entonces para que en el select no ponga 1 o 0 hice ese php.

Comment: @Miguel la tag <select></select> solo tiene 2 opciones

Comment: Cometi un error y no me fige bien, muentra con una imagen con haces tu select con el tag `td`

Comment: Perdón no te entendi bien, te muestre una imagen?

Comment: es que tu hablas de un select pero no se si hablas de un elemento de tipo select o una consulta ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Javascript para select

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(document).on('click', '.edit', function(){
            var id=$(this).val();

            //Obtener status
            var Estado=$('#select2-1'+id).children('span').first().text();

            //Convertir status a numero para asignar select
            if(Estado == 'Activado')
                $('select#select2-1').val(1).trigger('change');
            else
                $('select#select2-1').val(0).trigger('change');

        });
    });
```

Usando select2.js

Comment: Hola buenas podemos seguir intentandolo!??

Comment: Sí, no hay problema, ya probaste con $("select#select2-1 option[value=1]").attr("selected","selected") en lugar de $('select#select2-1').val(1)?

Comment: Lo acabo de probar y tampoco, el alert me devuelve el valor correcto, pero en el select sale primero Estado

Comment: Te dejo la prueba que hice https://jsfiddle.net/tc5a37bL/8/

Comment: Pero en el span mio hay que tener en cuenta que no sale el valor de Activado, Desactivado, en teoría sale el 1 o el 0.... Al menos eso es lo que sale de la BD, lo que pasa que con el PHP lo transformo en palabra.

Comment: Si, pero al momento de estar rendereado sale la palabra, no? o sale el 1, 0?

Comment: Cierto, sale la palabra! Quieres que te mande los archivos y los ves? Hay algún modo?

Comment: Puedes subirlos a un server y pasarme la liga para ver en vivo y probar, por otro lado revisa si pusiste bien el nombre del select, a veces uno se confunde

Comment: Ya vi el error, yo te pusé el código para un tag <select> y tu usas el de bootstrap, si le das click al select si te pone seleccionada la opción pero no la muestra en el div que simula el <select>, es bootstrap verdad?

Comment: Tienes toda la razón!!! :) y como se soluciona?

Comment: Perdón, es select2.js, según tengo entendido hay que ejecutar un trigger, debería ser algo así $('select').val('1').trigger('change'); suponiendo que la configuración de values sea 0 y 1

Comment: Pues asi si que funciona!!!! jajajajja que grande Christian!! Muchas gracias!

Comment: De nada! Para la proxima pregunta sería conveniente que pusieras el código del html en cuestión y las librarías que usas, sería más fácil llegar a la respuesta ;)

Comment: Lo tendré en cuenta, soy novatillo por aquí y tambien programando, pero bueno lo divertido es la aventura... Editas tu respuesta y te la doy por valida?

Comment: No te preocupes, igual soy novato aquí jajaja, ya la edité